# C++ variadic template, recursion decltype

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I know there are already a lot of questions concerning this topic, but so far I found no response that satisfactorily answers the following questions. Given the following code.

```
#include <map>

template<typename T, typename K>
std::map<T, K> map()
{
    return std::map<T, K>();
}

template<typename T, typename...K>
std::map<T, decltype(map<K...>())> map()
{
    return std::map<T, decltype(map<K...>())>();
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::map<int, int> m2 = map<int, int>();
    std::map<int, std::map<int, int>> m3 = map<int, int, int>();    
    std::map<int, std::map<int, std::map<int, int>>> m4 = map<int, int, int, int>();    // <- Compile Error here
    return 0;
}
```

A call to

```
map<int, int, int>()
```

shall return an object

```
std::map<int, std::map<int, int>>
```

and this works perfectly for up to three template parameters. 
As mentioned in the code calling the pair function with four template parameters fails and g++ (5.1.0) returns the following error.

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:20:84: error: no matching function for call to 'map()'
      std::map<int, std::map<int, std::map<int, int>>> m4 = map<int, int, int, int>(); // <- Compile Error here
                                                                                    ^
main.cpp:4:20: note: candidate: template<class T, class K> std::map<T, K> map()
     std::map<T, K> map()
                    ^
main.cpp:4:20: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:20:84: error: wrong number of template arguments (4, should be 2)
      std::map<int, std::map<int, std::map<int, int>>> m4 = map<int, int, int, int>(); // <- Compile Error here
                                                                                    ^
main.cpp:10:40: note: candidate: template<class T, class ... K> std::map<T, decltype (map<K ...>())> map()
     std::map<T, decltype(map<K...>())> map()
                                        ^
main.cpp:10:40: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp: In substitution of 'template<class T, class ... K> std::map<T, decltype (map<K ...>())> map() [with T = int; K = {int, int, int}]':
main.cpp:20:84:   required from here
main.cpp:10:35: error: no matching function for call to 'map()'
     std::map<T, decltype(map<K...>())> map()
                                   ^
main.cpp:4:20: note: candidate: template<class T, class K> std::map<T, K> map()
     std::map<T, K> map()
                    ^
main.cpp:4:20: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:10:35: error: wrong number of template arguments (3, should be 2)
     std::map<T, decltype(map<K...>())> map()
                                   ^
```

Therefore my questions are:

- Is this issue g++ related?
- What is the designated way to solve this problem?

Comment: The variadic version of `pair` is not in scope at the point of the `decltype`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why all this craziness to get a `pair` with `N` elements, instead of using a [`tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)?

Comment: @T.C. what would be the right solution?
so that a call to pair<int, int, int, int>() returns  std::pair<int, std::pair< int, std::pair< int, int>>> ?

Comment: @ltb68167 _"what would be the right solution?"_ Using a `std::tuple` as mentioned.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ of course using a std::tuple would be the better choice here. But this was out of curiosity, e.g. in case I substitute std::pair with std::map, what would I have to do then?

Comment: @CoryKramer of course you are right there, but what if I substitute std::pair with std::map ?

Comment: @ltb68167 You cannot substitute a (`std::vector<>` of)  `std::pair<>` seamlessly with a `std::map<>` these are completely different concepts.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Okay, I updated the example. What would be the right solution in this case?

Comment: @ltb68167 _" What would be the right solution in this case?"_ Use a `std::tuple<>` as value type for the `std::map<>`

Comment: @rici But is there no way to solve this problem recursivly, to created a nested map `std::map<int, std::map<int, std::map<int, int>>>` ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But is a `std::map<int, std::tuple<int, int, int>>` the same thing as `std::map<int, std::map<int, std::map<int, int>>>` ?

Comment: @ltb68167 _"... the same thing as ..."_ It's certainly not.

Comment: Actually, `std::map<std::tuple<int, int, int>, int>` would be better.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So is there no possibility to create the ugly nested map?

Comment: @ltb68167 You can always try my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manipulating types with types is usually easier.

```
template<class K0, class K1, class...Ks>
struct my_map;
template<class K0, class K1, class...Ks>
using my_map_t = typename my_map<K0,K1,Ks...>::type;


template<class K0, class K1>
struct my_map<K0,K1>{using type=std::map<K0, K1>;};

template<class K0, class K1, class K2, class...Ks>
struct my_map<K0, K1, K2, Ks...>{
  using type=std::map<K0, my_map_t<K1, K2, Ks...>>;
};
```

does what you want.

If you really want it as a function:

```
template<class K0, class K1, class...Ks>
my_map_t<K0, K1, Ks...> map() { return {}; }
```

does the trick.

A function is not in context during its own declaration, so your `map` overload cannot see itself as a valid candidate for `map` in its own return type.

You can get around this via ADL (both the context of its own declaration, and the ADL at point of function invocation, are considered to find overloads), but it isn't needed.

Comment: Ahh... I think I was missing the K2 part from my answer.
Oh well, let's take your answer as the good one.

Comment: @KABoissonneault yours also has a recursive call in `map`'s deduced return type, which won't resolve the way you want it to.

Comment: @Yakk thanks for your answer, so there is no way to do this without using structs or classes?

Comment: @ltb68167 It is possible if you have access to C++14 `auto` deduced return types (different from C++11 trailing return types). But it is much easier and cleaner to use structs.

Comment: @ltb68167 I said how to get around it in my last paragraph: use ADL to produce an overload search that can find the function itself.  The result is far less clean for the problem you are facing.  Think ugly.

Comment: Some verbosity can be reduced by avoiding K2 in my_map. Example: http://goo.gl/Kyabuz